# Thunar File Manager left side pane (tree view) configuration

Tags: xubuntu, thunar, tree-view

I don't know if it's possible but why when I select a folder in Thunar on left side pane (tree view) and hit for example "g" letter nothing happens? I would expect that the selection jumps to the first match of a folder or file beginning of a letter "g". This behavior works on right side pane (shortcuts view) as expected. Another issue - selected folder on left side pane then hit "enter" also nothing happens, I must have to hover the cursor over the expander then left click to open it. Can I change these settings ? Thanks, Vladi
PS: Thunar 1.6 , Xubuntu 16.0.5

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and Torsten_K's answer indicates that if the issue wasn't an installation-specific problem, it's probably overtaken by events anyway.  This isn't a direct answer to what was asked in the question, but an alternative that will solve the problem (in case someone else happens to run into the same issue and the underlying problem isn't confined to the OP's machine).  For others who don't have the problem, it's still an alternative you might want to check out.

Aside from the issue in the question, Thunar also has the shortcoming of not being able to display two side-by-side tabs so you can compare them or drag and drop between them (the impetus for my own search for a solution).  Xfce allows you to select a different default file manager (see the Settings Manager, Preferred Applications, Utilities tab).  Note that this setting only half works; it will launch the selected file manager when you ask for it, but it still uses Thunar for internally-triggered actions, like popping up the file manager view when you insert a USB drive.  So don't uninstall Thunar.

Changing the file manager is the alternative solution.  You can install any file manager you want, and there are many choices that will solve the problem in the question.  But check out [PCManFM](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM), (available in the repository).  I discovered it as the default file manager in LXDE; it was developed to be a replacement for Nautilus, Konqueror and Thunar.  It does what you're asking in the question.  It's a nice, full-featured file manager (I replaced Dolphin, my previous favorite, with it for distros with an inadequate bundled file manager).  It's tiny and fast, and well-behaved (some other distro flagship file managers become unreadable with certain themes when used in another distro).  A real find.